# How can I rebase part of a branch to the master branch?

Tags: git, git-rebase

Originally, I had something like this:

```
      C---D (branch1)
     /
A---B (master)
```

Because I needed to work on something else (which was unrelated to `branch1`), I decided to make a new branch (called `branch2`). I made a couple of commits on `branch2` and then pushed them.

Now, my intention was to have `master` as a root of `branch2`. However, I accidentally did this:

```
            E---F--G (branch2)
           /
      C---D (branch1)
     /
A---B (master)
```

Is there a clean way to make `branch2` stem directly from `master`, as shown below?

```
    E---F--G (branch2)
    |       
    | C---D (branch1)
    |/
A---B (master)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ASCII graphs in your question have an uncanny resemblance to those in the second example describing the usage of the `--onto` flag in the [`git-rebase` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase):

> Another example of `--onto` option is to rebase part of a branch. If
>   we have the following situation:
>
> ```
>             H---I---J topicB
>            /
>       E---F---G  topicA
>      /
> A---B---C---D  master
> ```
>
> then the command
>
> ```
> git rebase --onto master topicA topicB
> ```
>
> would result in:
>
> ```
>      H'--I'--J'  topicB
>     /
>     | E---F---G  topicA
>     |/
> A---B---C---D  master
> ```

That example indicates that you will land in the desired situation by running

```
git rebase --onto master branch1 branch2
```

**However**, you also write that you've already pushed `branch2` to some remote when your repo looked like your second ASCII graph. Are you sharing the remote in question with anybody else? In that case, think twice (or thrice!) before rebasing, as it's a form of history rewriting, and [you should never rewrite history has been shared](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing#The-Perils-of-Rebasing).

Comment: Great answer!  I didn't even know about `git rebase onto` and I consider myself an expert in Git rebasing.  @Løiten Please check if anyone had pulled branch2 since you pushed it.  If not, you can do a `git push origin branch2 --force` to force you rebased branch to the remote.

Comment: That's the right answer. It is possible that he will get conflicts to resolve though if changes in EFG are connected to changes in CD.

Comment: @chmike No conflicts should arise, in this case: `git-rebase` will know what to do without user intervention, because the operation simply consists in replaying a bunch of commits on top of an older ancestor.

Comment: Well I tested it on a single file and got conflicts. The changes (diffs) in EFG have to be independent of CD.

Comment: @chmike That goes against my intuition, but I must admit I haven't tested it. I'll get back to you after doing that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and for pointing me to the proper [git-docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) page :). The remote is shared with several people, but should not cause a problem since I'm the only one working on the branches, and no-one has pushed or pulled in the meantime. I tried the proposed solution, but got conflicts like @chmike, which I am currently trying to resolve.

Comment: @Løiten You *have to* use rebase to end up in the desired state. If conflicts arise in the process, tough luck; there is no way around them. In this respect, my answer is correct. As for the remote being shared... How do you know that people haven't pulled in the meantime? There is also a risk of somebody pushing to the remote right before you attempt to push. Tread carefully...