# Rebase only part of a branch

Tags: git

I've got two branches (and master). Branch 2 is based on Branch 1 is based on master. I've submitted Branch 1 for review, it had some changes, I rebased some of those changes into history and merged the result into master.

Now I need to rebase Branch 2 on top of master to prepare it for review/merge.

The problem is that Branch 2 still contains the original commits of Branch 1, which don't exist anymore, so git gets confused. I tried rebase -i to drop the original commits of Branch 1, but the commits of Branch 2 don't base on top of master-before-branch-1.

What I need to do is take branch 2, drop some commits, and rebase just the remaining commits on top of master in a single operation. But I only know how to do these two operations in two distinct steps.

How can I rebase part of my branch onto another branch, dropping all commits that are not in common ancestry, except the ones I specify (e.g. from HEAD~2 up)?

Here's the current state:

```
master                     new branch 1
- - - - - - - - - - - | - - - - - - - - -
    \
     \   branch 1
      \ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
                     \
                      \     branch 2
                       \ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
```

What I want to end up with:

```
master            new branch 1    
- - - - - - - | - - - - - - - - - -
                                   \
                                    \
                                     \
                                      \    branch 2
                                       - - - - - - - - -
```

Comment: An ASCII graph representing the state of your repo would help. At first glance, I'd say you're looking for [`git rebase --onto`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase). See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28715619/how-can-i-rebase-part-of-a-branch-to-the-master-branch/28715930#28715930

Comment: Better! See also the top of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25488138/move-initial-commits-off-master-to-another-branch-in-git/25490288#25490288

Comment: git rebase --onto nearly worked for me. I did `git rebase --onto master --root HEAD~1`, but for some reason it picked three commits to bring with me instead of only `HEAD~1` and upwards. Furthermore, instead of rebasing my branch, I'm now in detached HEAD state.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The solution is considerably simpler than I expected. It turns out that you can supply `-i` to a much larger variety of rebase commands (I thought it was only for rebasing a branch to itself for changing history). So I simply ran `git rebase -i master` and dropped those extra commits.

Comment: To clarify what @Puppy did was do an interactive rebase from branch 2 onto new branch 1  (`git rebase -i new_branch_1` while on branch 2) and removed all the branch 1 commits using the interactive console so only branch 2's commits were played.

Comment: Yes, doing `git checkout branch-to-move && git rebase -i new-parent-branch` and keeping only lines that match the patches you want to keep works fine. Just be really careful not to drop any patch you don't want to lose.

Answer (score 124):

The actual command would be:

```
git rebase --onto newbranch1 branch1 branch2
```

That will replay on top of `new_branch1` all commits *after* `branch1` up to `branch2` HEAD.

As [Joshua Goldberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/411282/joshua-goldberg) puts it [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34926253/rebase-only-part-of-a-branch/34927492?noredirect=1#comment95454838_34927492):

```
 git rebase --onto <place-to-put-it> <last-change-that-should-NOT-move> <change to move>
```

As [Denis Sivtsov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10951191/denis-sivtsov) illustrates in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34926253/rebase-only-part-of-a-branch/34927492#comment114941014_34927492):

> If you need only replay the last commit only from branch, in this case work:
>
> ```
> git rebase --onto newbranch1 HEAD~1
> ```

Comment: It sure does (was about to post the same myself). Incidentally, `git help rebase` covers this case.

Comment: @TomFenech even better than `git help rebase`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2369516/6309 (my old 2010 answer) ;)

Comment: The tricky thing for me was understanding that "upstream" in the help means the change to hold still.  `git rebase —onto <place-to-put-it>  <last-change-that-should-NOT-move> <change to move>`

Comment: @JoshuaGoldberg Yes: that is what I meant by "all commits *after* branch1". I have included your command in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: If you need only replay the last commit only from branch, in this case work git rebase --onto newbranch1 HEAD~1

Comment: @DenisSivtsov True. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 19):

```
git rebase --onto master HEAD~2
```

- **`master`** - the branch you're rebasing onto
- **`2`** - the last n commits from the current branch you need rebased

<sub>[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39085045/1678614)</sub>

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I find your ASCII graph a bit ambiguous, as branches don't really represent a range of commits - a branch points to a specific commit. I take it you mean something like

```
H (new-branch-1)
G
| F (HEAD -> branch-2)
| E
| D (branch-1)
| C
|/
B (master)
A
```

in which case the goal, and result of [VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34927492/3217306) `git rebase --onto new-branch-1 branch-1 branch-2`, is

```
F' (HEAD -> branch-2)
E'
H (new-branch-1)
G
| D (branch-1)
| C
|/
B (master)
A
```

But [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34926593/3217306) `git rebase -i master` doesn't make sense. Surely you would mean `git rebase -i new-branch-1` and in the editor write

```
drop C
drop D
pick E
pick F
```

which would achieve the goal above.

(Your answer would result in):

```
F' (HEAD -> branch-2)
E'
| H (new-branch-1)
| G
|/ 
| D (branch-1)
| C
|/
B (master)
A
```

Answer (score 1):

As answered, you can do this using `--onto`.

I find the `git rebase --onto` syntax quite confusing. So I created this script for rebasing "nested" branches: [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/OndraZizka/2a2b167225b3f4e05a4ae3c4796432fd)

In your example, you would call:

`moveBranch newBranch2 from newBranch1 to master`

```
#!/bin/bash

## Places a branch to a new base. 
## Useful when splitting a long branch to multiple pull requests.
##
##   ---+--------master 
##       \
##         --- A ---- B
## 
## git-moveBranch.sh B from A to master
##
##   ---+-------- master ---- B
##       \
##         --- A 


function printUsageAndExit() {
    echo "Usage: moveBranch <branch> from <previous-base> to <new-base>";
    exit 1;
}

if [ 5 != $# ] ; then printUsageAndExit; fi
if [ "$2" != "from" ] ; then printUsageAndExit; fi
if [ "$4" != "to" ] ; then printUsageAndExit; fi

WHAT="$1"
FROM="$3"
ONTO="$5"

echo "Running:   git rebase —-onto=\"$ONTO\" \"$FROM\" \"$WHAT\""
# git rebase —-onto <place-to-put-it> <last-change-that-should-NOT-move> <change to move>
git rebase --onto "$ONTO" "$FROM" "$WHAT"
```