# How to rebase only last two commits without the whole branch?

Tags: git

I accidentally committed to a wrong branch. The graph looks like this

```
----o--o-----o (master)
     \
      \
       A--B--C--D (feature)
```

I want to move C and D to master without the changes in A and B. I want the graph to look like this

```
----o--o-----o (master)
     \        \
      \        C--D (other_feature)
       \
        A--B (feature)
```

is this possible? and how to do it also on remote?

Changes in A and B are not going to be merged so I don't care if the commits will be lost

Comment: Is the `feature` branch with commits `C` and `D` already published?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Warning:** The following git commands will rewrite the history of the `feature` branch. `git rebase` and `git reset` are dangerous because it can wreak havoc for anyone else who is using the `feature` branch.

First create the branch `other_feature` at the same commit as `feature`.

```
git checkout -b other_feature feature
```

Rebase the previous two commits onto `master`.

```
git rebase --onto master HEAD~2
```

Checkout `feature`.

```
git checkout feature
```

Reset `feature` to the commit where you want it.

```
git reset --hard HEAD~2
```

Comment: Warning: This answer _rewrites_ the history of the `feature` branch.  While this may be OK for this particular problem, this course of action should be taken with caution in general, because it can wreak havoc for anyone else who is using the `feature` branch.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks for the warning. I have edited my answer with similar wording.

Comment: For me, `feature` branch was unchanged, while only last two commits were rebased, so commits A and B stayed the same at a first glance (C and D stayed too, but I used `reset --hard <B_id>`). Maybe there is some difference that's not apparent but it looks fine now...

Comment: @Zygro As far as the commit history is concerned, my answer will solve your problem. See the warning in Tim Biegeleisen's comment and at the top of my edited post for potential pitfalls from this approach.

Answer (score 2):

The following answer presumes that your `feature` branch is already published to the remote.  I would just cherry pick commits `C` and `D` from the `feature` branch onto the `master` branch, and then revert these two commits on `feature`:

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b other_feature
git cherry-pick <SHA-1 for C>
git cherry-pick <SHA-1 for D>

git checkout feature
git revert <SHA-1 for C>
git revert <SHA-1 for D>
```

Comment: Doesn't `git revert` create two new commits that "undo" the two previous commits?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice The OP may not be aware that rewriting history of a published branch can cause problems.  This is why I avoided rebasing and resetting in my answer.

Comment: That's a good point. I should add a caveat to my answer. I usually assume that feature branches aren't used by other developers.

Comment: Rather than cherry picking directly onto master, create an `other_feature` branch.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Your rebase --onto answer is for sure the way to go here, but using cherry pick is still a valid alternative.

Comment: Yes, your solution is viable. For some reason I missed that you have `git checkout -b other_feature` and thought you were cherry picking directly to master.